# Spring Data Rest PATCH add to embedded list

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, patch, spring-data-rest

I'm having difficulty adding to an embedded list using Spring Data Rest and a PATCH request. I'm using MongoDB so no JPA joins (ManyToOne etc) here, just a plain old regular embedded List of child type.

My beans look like this:

```
class Parent {
  String name;
  List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
  String name;
}
```

My request looks like this:

```
curl -d '{"children": [ {"name": "bob"} ] }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/parent/123
```

The result of this is that all the child elements are replaced with the new one from the request, e.g.

```
old:     [ 'tom', 'sally' ]
request: [ 'bob' ]
expected result: [ 'tom', 'sally', 'bob']
actual result:   [ 'bob' ]
```

I've stepped through the Spring code (DomainObjectReader) and it just doesn't seem to handle my scenario but surely this is a really simple use case, any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: *this is a really simple use case*. If you think about it, how exactly can the framework determine whether you wanted to add to the collection or simply replace it. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is tha you try to edit the parent object, instead of the relationship collection.

1. You need to create a child:

```
   POST /api/child  {...}
```

which returns a url to the newly created child (either in the location header or as a self link in the response - based on your SDR settings)

2. Then add this child to the parent's children collection:

```
   PATCH /api/parent/123/children
   Content-Type:text/uri-list
   body: ***the URI of the child***
```